# Extracting a piece of code with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a help on a Regular Expression, I'm reading by ajax an external URL which content the following code:

```
<body>
originalAdvertiserLink='http://normaldomain.com/7cc86d4999/'<div id='beacon_d14503cb95' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://URL.com/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=451&amp;campaignid=91&amp;zoneid=19&amp;loc=1&amp;cb=d14503cb95' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' /></div>
</body>
```

I need to extract the URL inside originalAdvertiserLink='' which I already do with this code:

```
var e = /originalAdvertiserLink=\'([^\']*)/.exec(data);
openxOriginalLink = e[1];
```

But I also need to extract all the div tag, I mean this part only:

```
<div id='beacon_d14503cb95' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://URL.com/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=451&amp;campaignid=91&amp;zoneid=19&amp;loc=1&amp;cb=d14503cb95' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' /></div>
```

how do I write a regex to extract only that part as I do with the URL above?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you use hidden inputs and `data-*` attributes? Don't parse and regex HTML, it's awful and easy to break.

Comment: Just parse the HTML as DOM and access the nodes?

Comment: @Saymon, you can only reply to people who are currently active in this comments chain.  Dystroy won't see your comment.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? When you get your ajax response from the URL, what kind of data is returned (html;json;xml)?

Comment: @Felix Kling I already have all the HTML content into a variable, but I am not sure what you mean or how to pull out that exactly node

Comment: Thanks @gdoron I did not know. Responding your question, there are more code involved (cross-domain, etc...) where will be very hard to me use idden input or alter the code that I already have.

Comment: @tftd it is returned as plain text

Comment: Fixing the exiting code would be a lot smarter than continuing with the horrific code that cause HTML regex parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of (if you don't want to change your current way of doing things - not recommended by the comments):

```
var body = "<body>originalAdvertiserLink='http://normaldomain.com/7cc86d4999/'<div id='beacon_d14503cb95' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://URL.com/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=451&amp;campaignid=91&amp;zoneid=19&amp;loc=1&amp;cb=d14503cb95' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' /></div></body>";

var regex = /<div(.*?)div>/ig;
var match = regex.exec(body); 

if(match.length > 0)
{
    match =  match[0]; 
    alert(match);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56dKY/

Comment: Thanks @meewoK this is what I was looking for to avoid re-design the code.